# Subscribing for slf4j realtime log?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

Definition of the problem : there is an application in a separate java process, and we want to stream its realtime log to other applications when necessary (on demand).

Application uses slf4j, **is there a possibility to have access to real time log output of slf4j?** I want to avoid scanning latest log file...

Ideally i imagine there to be possibility to pass a consumer of a message like `Consumer<String>` (or better consumer of a batch of messages `Consumer<Collection<String>>`) which will be called asynchronously on every log message...

**any ideas how this can be achieved?**

Comment: Did you consider using some type of queue like Kafka or ActiveMQ? Just an idea, I hope that can help.

Comment: No i dont need message queue like kafka, more than that i want to make this pluggable, so that if you turned streaming off you cause no overhead to logging framework... this is gonna be enabled only when application is working in realtime but is mulfunctioning...

Comment: this should be simple thing, i just hoped that there is something better than creating a different appender etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `SLF4J` is just a logging facade, but the implementations have all kinds of different *appenders* that allow you to send the logging events to all sorts of different places. The text file is just the one people usually use when they don't have any special requirements for logging. There are appenders for JMS queues, sockets, databases and dozens others.

That should give you plenty of possibilities to consider.

Comment: so i shall implement specific appender for my actual implementation of logger (say log4j) ?

Comment: You don't need to implement an appender, just use one.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding slf4j is abstraction of the logging framework. We can wrap different logging frameworks. So, slf4j doesn't have any options to do that. We can solve your problem with below options

- You require transaction log of the other system. May be we can
  implement the Database appender on other system to log the
  transactions. I can read by connecting to db.
- You can expose rest service from the other system that will read log
  file and post to your environment.